# Write xlsx file in R

Tags: r, excel, export, export-to-excel

```
       鏃ユ湡 AQI 鑼冨洿 璐ㄩ噺绛夌骇 PM2.5  PM10  SO2    CO   NO2  O3 鎺掑悕
1  2015-04-01 106 67~144  杞诲害姹℃煋  79.3 105.1 20.2 1.230  89.5  76    308
2  2015-04-02  74 31~140       鑹\xaf  48.1  79.7 18.8 1.066  51.5 129    231
3  2015-04-03  98 49~136       鑹\xaf  72.9  89.2 16.0 1.323  50.9  62    293
4  2015-04-04  92 56~158       鑹\xaf  67.6  78.2 14.3 1.506  57.4  93    262
```

My code is,

```
write.xlsx(a, "./pollution.xlsx", sheetName = "test")
```

a is the dataframe above. I got an error,

> Error in .jnew("java/io/FileOutputStream", jFile) :
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\pollution.xlsx (鍙︿竴涓▼搴忔鍦ㄤ娇鐢ㄦ鏂囦)

I want to know how to fix this problem.

Comment: Based on your exception, your file is not found.  Why not try with absolute paths instead of relative?  Once you get it working, figure out what your relative path is in comparison to where your pollution.xlsx file is.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I have another question, do you know why I got the messy code like 鏃ユ湡? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Just try to download latest java version in your workstation and set java home inside R

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7")
```